# Installing Ruby on Rails for OSX - Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, installation

I am having trouble installing Ruby on Rails on OSX. I have gotten as far as too install the Rails, and have it create the application skeleton but when I go to run the server to test it's all working I get this:

> Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.

sqlite is in the gem folder/list:

> *** LOCAL GEMS ***
>
> sqlite3-ruby (1.2.4)

Any idea?

Comment: Did you run 'bundle install'? Does require 'sqlite3' work in your console? if not, please show an exception

Comment: which rails version do you use? try `gem install bundler' and after that `bundler install` to install al the gems you need for your application.

Comment: @Michael Bundler is a dependency of rails now.

Comment: @Vlad - Done bundle install and sqlite3 does appear in the console...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out solution was here:

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1074909